# blackberry's j2me configuration and profile

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I'm sorry for asking a none-programming question, if it is.

I'm working on a library project that must be compatible through various mobile platforms.

- I found some `Java TV` platforms are constructed on `CDC/PBP`.
- I found `Android` api (partially) based on the `Java 6`.
- And I want to know, is `blackberry` sill on the `CLDC/MIDP`?

According to [Programming the BlackBerry With J2ME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139239.html), it seems so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they support MIDP 2.0/CLDC 1.1 and a good number of JSRs. Devices running OS 5.0 and higher have MIDP 2.1 support. Also there are the RIM custom APIs some of which can be used in BlackBerry MIDlets too.

More info [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/9114/Java_ME_and_Java_APIs_for_BB_446980_11.jsp).

UPDATE:
For the new BB10 OS there's the possibility of repackaging an already existing Android app so that it can be run (with some issues) in the [Android Runtime](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/).